# What is the way to find the price with by the quantity in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Rails version: `7.0`

PostgreSQL version: `14`

What is the way to find the price by the quantity in the `products` table?

#### `products` table

```
min_quantity | max_quantity | price
1            | 4            | 200
5            | 9            | 185
10           | 24           | 175
25           | 34           | 150
35           | 999          | 100
1000         | null         | 60
```

#### Expected result

```
3       ===> 200
50      ===> 100
2500    ===> 60
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that with a where condition checking that the given value is between `min_quantity` and `max_quantity`;

```
with products(min_quantity, max_quantity, price) as (
  values
    (1,  4, 200)
  , (5,  9, 185)
  , (10,  24, 175)
  , (25,  34, 150)
  , (35,  999, 100)
  , (1000,  null, 60)
)
select
  price
from products
where
  case
  when max_quantity is null
  then 3 >= min_quantity
  else
    3 between min_quantity and max_quantity
  end
-- 200
```

But as you might have a null value for max_quantity when the `min_quantity` is 1000 then you'll need a way to handle that. So you can use a case expression to only compare the input with `min_quantity`.

If the same applies for `min_quantity` and it can hold null values, then another branch in the case expression might suffice.

As Rails doesn't have specific support for these situations, you'll be off to go with just "raw" SQL in your `where`;

```
where(<<~SQL, input: input)
  where
  case
  when max_quantity is null
  then :input > min_quantity
  else
    :input between min_quantity and max_quantity
  end
SQL
```

Comment: Thank you! But I was looking for the solution in Rails.